# Phantomjs in handling onclick events using ruby-selenium

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, selenium

```
<INPUT onclick="return verifyCheckedForEdit('UserAdminForm', 'itemDelUserId','hiddenUserId', 'Disable')" id=disableButton class=buttonBlue type=submit value=Disable name=Disable>
```

The above is my tag.I tried various options:

```
disable=$driver.find_element(:xpath,"html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/input[2]")
```

- disable.submit
- $driver.find_element(:name,"Disable").send_keys :enter
- $driver.action.move_to(disable).double_click(disable).perform
- $driver.action.move_to(disable).click(disable).perform

Nonone of the above work to click this button.

Answer (score 0):

I am taking a screenshot after the click however I notice that the screenshot does not have the modal window using phantom js:

I tried to maximize the screen:
$driver.manage.window.maximize

And then I tried to click confirm on the window. But nothing happens.So I am stuck with not knowing if phantomjs actually rendered the modal window and also is it actually clicking on the modal popup.

I found a solution for this if anybody needs it:

```
$driver.execute_script('window.alert = function(){};')
$driver.execute_script('window.confirm = function(confirmationText) {return true; };')
delete=$driver.find_element(:name,"Delete").click
```

Before you click on the disable/delete button please create a modal window and then click on it.